# How to add text to element without affecting it child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML hierarchy like the one here

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="el_01">
        <div class="title">
            <span class="openClose"></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I like to do is to add text element for `.title` div without removing span element.

Comment: text element means input text?

Comment: use `$(".title").append("Your text element here");`

Comment: Yeah.. This is what i want.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will append input text element in `.title` div.

```
$(".title").append("<input type='text' />");
```

It will append simple text into .title div:

```
$('<p>Hello All</p>').appendTo('.title');
```

```js
$(".title").append("<input type='text' />");
$('<p>Hello All</p>').appendTo('.title');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist">
<li id="el_01">
    <div class="title">
        <span class="openClose"></span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Question is about inserting text only adn without any parent element.

Comment: isnt this working for you $(".title").append("<input type='text'>");